# Picture taken from camera getting blur

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I have integrated crop image library in my application which have function for take and use picture taken via camera. My developer have done it as expected but now when I have checked via take picture from camera than after take picture and set it on crop page, its getting blur before we set it.My developer is out of coverage for some task. I have asked library developer and they have given me solution for integrate code like below

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
```

and My developer have integrated code like below in my application

```
    @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent,REQ_PHOTO_CAMERA);
                            }
                        }
```

as well method like below

```
    public final int REQ_PHOTO_CAMERA=243;
public final int REQ_PHOTO_GALLERY=346;
public final int REQ_APP_GALLERY=427;

public final int ACTION_CHANGE_BACKGROUND=1;
public final int ACTION_CHANGE_AUTHOR=2;

private int mChangeAction;

public void onActivityResult(int req,int res,Intent data){
    if(res==RESULT_OK){
        if(req==REQ_PHOTO_CAMERA){
            Bitmap  cameraImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            cropAndSaveImage(cameraImg);
            //updateCustomImage(cameraImg);
        }else if(req==REQ_PHOTO_GALLERY){

            try {
                Bitmap imgGallery = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
               // updateCustomImage(imgGallery);
                cropAndSaveImage(imgGallery);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               // e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if (req == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
            Log.e("ImageUrl",resultUri.getPath());
            updateCustomImage(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(resultUri.getPath()));
        }else if(req==REQ_APP_GALLERY){

            String imgPath=data.getStringExtra("ImagePath");
            try {
                InputStream inputStream=getAssets().open(imgPath);
                Bitmap image=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                cropAndSaveImage(image);
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }

        }
    }
}



public void cropAndSaveImage(Bitmap imgPicked){
    ImageLoader.getInstance().saveTempImage(imgPicked);
    CropImage.activity(ImageLoader.getInstance().getTempImageUri())
            .setInitialCropWindowPaddingRatio(0)
            .setFixAspectRatio(false)
            .setAspectRatio(1,2)
            .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
            .start(this);
}
```

let me know what I am missing ?

Note : we have used this library : [Link](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper)

Thanks

Comment: You should also check if this happen on different devices. Its hard to tell if its just caused by low quality camera or some sort of unintended code behavior.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks sir ! I have checked in 4-5 device and getting issue in all device, library developer have also given solution for it that I have written in first code block, but I do not know how can I attach it in my code

Comment: This code produce a blurry image `Bitmap  cameraImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");` , since It is used for thumbnail only.

Comment: so how can I solve it ?

Comment: Instead get the Bitmap using the URI and the not Bitmap coming from the Intent.

Answer (score 1):

Your original image taken using camera will be here-

```
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getExternalCacheDir().getPath(), "pickImageResult.jpeg"));
```

in this file.

the **Bitmap  cameraImg = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");** is just a thumbnail returned.

Comment: just keep the location of file you provided while sending capture image intent and then in onActivityResult(int req,int res,Intent data) just use that file instead of bitmap from Intent data.